# Too much space between author and year in apacite citations

Tags: spacing, citing, apa-style

Does anyone else feel that there's too much whitespace between author and year in the following example (note the red brackets)? Or is it proper standard and just annoys me because I'm not used to it?

[image: citation with too much spacing]

If you agree; how would I go about removing it, considering the following minmal working example?

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{sample}
\begin{document}
    \noindent \citep{bundesen2005,logan1996,logan2001,logan2002}.
\end{document}
```

[sample.bib](http://paste.debian.net/plainh/e43579c6)

Comment: LaTeX tries to find a good breaking point. However in your constellation there is no good breaking point. Maybe you can rewrite your sentence so that you get a better spacing layout.

Comment: Yes, that might be it. But then again there are occasions where LaTeX doesn't need to pay attention to justified aligning and it happens nonetheless. For example at the end of a paragraph (http://i.stack.imgur.com/t0zgu.png).

Comment: I have the same problem and I don't think it is because of LaTeX finding no good breaking point. It is consistent all over the document, in every citation after the comma of the last author and the year.
Maybe it is an apacite bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug in `apacite` that should be reported to its maintainer(s).

`apacite` defines several punctuation macros like `\BBAY` for the punctuation between authors and year in a citation. For example, `\BBAY` is `,`, a comma and a space. With the `natbibapa` option the `natbib` package is used, and there the punctuation is set set with `\bibpunct` (among other methods). However, `\bibpunct` only wants the actual punctuation character, in this case the comma, and sets spaces by itself. So it is `apacite`'s bug to feed `\BBAY` and the like to `\bibpunct`.

This can be repaired easily:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\AtBeginDocument{%
\renewcommand{\BBAY}{,}%% punctuation between authors and year
\renewcommand{\BBC}{;}%% punctuation between multiple cites
\renewcommand{\BBYY}{,}%% punctuation between multiple years
}

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{sample}
\begin{document}
    \noindent \citep{bundesen2005,logan1996,logan2001,logan2002}.
\end{document}
```

Note that `apacite` has more spacing issues in the reference list, but glancing at the bibliography style they seem to be intended. Also, using the ampersand in the authors list (preceded by a comma no less!) seems odd, too.

[image: sample output]

Comment: Thanks for the indepth answer. I sent the author an email regarding this issue.

Comment: Erik Meijer, the apacite author, already has this (and several other natbib related spacing issues) fixed and  intends to upload a new apacite version this weekend.